# Absolutely Nothing Apearing in "Additional Drivers"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I just got Ubuntu the other month or so. I'm running the 11.04 version currently and trying to install drivers for a Nvidia graphics card (it's my brother's computer and he currently cannot find the number of the card right now).

I read that, to install the proper drivers for gaming, I would need to go into "**Additional Drivers**" and choose them myself. I clicked to go into "Additional Drivers" and it searched "for available drivers", then opened the additional drivers list. Lo and Behold, there was nothing, simply the message "**No proprietary drivers are in use on this system**" and the **Help** and **Close** buttons.

Sorry if there's some silly simple answer to all of this, I'm new to this sort of thing (used to Windows simplicity, lol) and I really don't know what to do. Help would be much appreciated.

Also, I should mention that the graphics card was installed and ran fine before switching from Windows XP to Ubuntu.

Comment: To check what kind of graphic card your computer is using, type `ls_pci` and `ls_pci -a` in a terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by January, can you post the output of `lspci -a` ?

If you're positive that it's a nvidia card, you can always install the nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Once you've installed those, you can generate a new default Xorg configuration file to make sure you'll use the nvidia proprietary drivers:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Finally restart your computer and you should be running the nvidia driver.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the driver for this graphic card is already included in the kernel, so you don't have to install a prorietary one.

Comment: Of course there is a driver in the kernel, but "Additional Drivers" exists for installing proprietary drivers that in most cases provide better performance. A huge part of modern proprietary graphics drivers are optimizations for certain programs. Sometimes those optimizations can be called cheating.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing shows up in the additional drivers try
    sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
this should show you the drivers if they are present in the kernel
Otherwise refer to this
[Why aren't 3d effects working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132275/why-arent-3d-effects-working)

Answer (score 0):

I found nothing in the "additional drivers" for my HP Pavilion 17 f1053us.  I was getting frustrated by the 800x600 resolution.  I managed **to get Synaptic installed** (Ubuntu Software Center is fundamentally inoperable at a low resolution). I used synaptic **to install anything/everything that seemed relevant to ATI**.

I then rebooted the machine and it came up in the native 1600x900 display mode! Perhaps this will work for you.

- xserver-xorg-video-radeon-dt... - X.org X server - AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
- [xserver-xorg-video-ati [image: Install xserver-xorg-video-ati]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xserver-xorg-video-ati) - X.org X server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
- [fglrx [image: Install fglrx]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/fglrx) - Video Driver for the AMD graphics accelerators
- [xserver-xorg-video-radeon [image: Install xserver-xorg-video-radeon]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xserver-xorg-video-radeon)
- [xserver-xorg-video-mach64 [image: Install xserver-xorg-video-mach64]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xserver-xorg-video-mach64)
- [xserver-xorg-video-r128 [image: Install xserver-xorg-video-r128]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xserver-xorg-video-r128)

One way to install the Synaptic package manager in the first place is to open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Comment: Is `xserver-xorg-video-radeon-dt` a specific package name? I can't find any package whose name is or begins with that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the repository by the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/ /"
```

My case above is for `ubuntu1604`, you should replace this part if your system is not ubuntu1604. The official reference is available via [enter link description here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html)

After the above command, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you reopen the Software $ Updates, will see NVIDIA binary drivers with "(propriety)". These drivers support CUDA after you type `nvidia-smi`