# libGL.so.1 is missing after changing graphics card - unable to run Steam

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, intel-graphics, steam

Since my graphics driver update failed and Ubuntu 12.04 64Bit couldn't load the driver, and I changed to use the on-board graphics hardware, `steam` isn't able to start. It just tells me:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
```

When I then click `OK` its says:

```
Fatal error: Failed to load steamui.so
```

can anyone Help me? Any Idea how i can get this lib back?

Edit it seems I already have this lib,..

```
locate libGLU.so.1
/home/sebastian/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/home/sebastian/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.08004
/home/sebastian/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/home/sebastian/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.08004
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.08004
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.08004
```

Comment: I edited my post hope taht will help yu / us to find a solution

Comment: I Solved it!

I followed the instructions [here][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132275/why-arent-3d-effects-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe im wrong but, im using nvidia card and libgl.so* is part of my nvidia driver.i use nvidia proprietary driver.Maybe coz u changed ur card so the driver not load properly.  So u can try to remove ur driver first . REBOOT, and try to reinstall ur graphics driver again. Try using additional driver menu in dash, maybe there is a best (recommend) driver for ur card.

Comment: I had a Nvidia graficcard in my PC before but i removed it now.
Now i have an `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)`

Comment: I Solved it!

I followed the instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132275/why-arent-3d-effects-working